# How to pass parameters with jquery proxy() to a function which has already other parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing

As asked, i have updated the code to my specific issue:

```
function A(){
    this.data1 = null;
    this.data2 = null;
}
A.prototype.receiveData1AndData2FromServer = function(callback){
    this.doneCallback = $.proxy( function foo(importantData, callback){
        this.data1 = importantData.data1;
        this.data2 = importantData.data2;
        callback != undefined ? callback() : null;
    }, this, callback);

    checkFail = $.proxy(
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            try {
                var str = new String(jqXHR.responseText);
                var result = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf('{')));
                this.doneCallback(result);
            } catch (ex) { console.log(ex); }
        }
    , this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: 'get_data1_and_data2.php', data: { 'id': this.id }, dataType: 'json'
    }).done(this.doneCallback)
    .fail(checkFail);
    }
```

(The problem is that the callback parameter is replacing the first parameter(importantData) instead of the second.)

There are calls with different callback parameter to A::receiveData1AndData2FromServer.
I want to pass the callback to A::doneCallback, so when the retrieval is done, the right callback will be called.

Comment: This looks hinky, try explaining exactly what you're trying to do, as surely there are other ways than this `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution after some thinking.
Splitting the context argument into an object with multiple fields(context and desired arguments) had solved it. I hope it will be useful for someone else.

```
function A(){
    this.data1 = null;
    this.data2 = null;
}
A.prototype.receiveData1AndData2FromServer = function(callback){
    this.doneCallback = $.proxy( function foo(importantData, callback){
        this.context.data1 = importantData.data1;
        this.context.data2 = importantData.data2;
        this.callback.callback != undefined ? this.callback() : null;
    }, {context:this, callback:callback});

    checkFail = $.proxy(
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            try {
                var str = new String(jqXHR.responseText);
                var result = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf('{')));
                this.doneCallback(result);
            } catch (ex) { console.log(ex); }
        }
    , this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: 'get_data1_and_data2.php', data: { 'id': this.id }, dataType: 'json'
    }).done(this.doneCallback)
    .fail(checkFail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context-additionalArguments) supports multiple arguments since version 1.6